# StackOverflow, what is done to page elements to fade out "ignored" tags?

Tags: support, jquery, google-chrome

I have set up a fair amount of ignored tags on SO, and after installing [gleebox](http://thegleebox.com/) for Chrome, and finding the [SO selector](http://tipjar.thegleebox.com/stack-overflow-results/) for it, I thought about trying to modify it to only highlight questions with tags I haven't tagged as ignored.

For those who don't know, gleebox is a sort of command line input area that pops up in chrome on a hotkey, and when it does, I can configure it with a jQuery selector to highlight, and let me keyboard-navigate through, links on a page. The selector for SO highlights all questions, and I'd like for it to only pick up questions I find interesting.

The selector is `h3>a` which I assume means "all a-elements inside h3-elements". I used the Chrome html-inspector to try to find differences between the interesting, unmarked, and uninteresting, questions but it seems that this inspector only picks up data from the html that was sent to me from the server, not the changes that jQuery applies afterwards.

So does anyone know what the fade-out code actually does to tags, and whether a jQuery-selector could be written to only select those that does not have the "uninteresting" effect applied to them?

If easier, for it to only select those that have the "interesting" effect would be a compromise.

Comment: +1 for telling me about Gleebox - looks interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For only going through the questions marked as interesting, use the selector:
`div.tagged-interesting>div>h3>a`

And for going through all questions except the ones marked ignored,

`h3>a:not(div.tagged-ignored>div>h3>a)`

I added them to the [TipJar](http://tipjar.thegleebox.com). You're welcome to add your own selectors there.

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I wanted!